# Mime types for custom file type

Tags: linux, mime-types

I'm trying to register a custom file type as a mime-type in linux. My custom filetype, with a custom extension, is actually a zip archive containing various xml and other files.

The problem I'm having is that my operating system (kubuntu) won't recognize the file as my custom mime-type but insists on it being a zip file.

I'm not sure where I should start trying to fix my problem. I've used the following mime info file (tugraz-caleydo.sharedmimeinfo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
<mime-type type="application/x-cal">  
<comment>Caleydo Project</comment>
<glob pattern="*.cal"/>
</mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

My Desktop Entry (caleydo.desktop, correctly registered in /usr/share/applications):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=2.01
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Caleydo
GenericName=Data Visualization 
Comment=Visualization for Molecular Biology
Exec=/usr/bin/caleydo
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/caleydo_256.png
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Science;
MimeType=application/x-cal;
```

And these are the commands I'm trying to use:

```
sudo xdg-mime install --mode system tugraz-caleydo.sharedmimeinfo
sudo xdg-mime default caleydo.desktop application/x-cal
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

However, this still gives me:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype export_2012.cal 
application/zip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the issue:

the mime info file has to have exactly the name of the mime type. Renaming it to x-cal.xml did the trick.